# Integrate javascript module with native SDK

Tags: javascript, android, ios, nativescript, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a React Web Application running inside a WebView using Cordova.

I need to integrate the javascript context with a third party native SDK.

I have used JNI in the past that allowed communication from JAVA to C code. Is there something similar for Javascript to JAVA (Android) and to Objective-C / Swift (iOS)?

My understanding is that we cannot simply develop a Cordova [plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) since the "JNI-like" communication has to be in plain Javascript. That's because the integration with the native SDK is done by a third party script that we inject in our Cordova App.

So now the **QUESTION** is: how can the developers of the 3rd party script invoke functions of a native SDK via javascript?
I have seen this project called [NativeScript](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript). Would this work in a WebView?

Comment: I'm unclear on why a Cordova plugin is out; this is the exact purpose for one. You said that the JNI-like communication needs to be in Javascript, which is going to be part of the plugin, but there will need to be a part written in Java and in Objective-C/ Swift . This is the similar to JNI: part of what you do is in Java, but someone has to write some C code to expose the functionality.

Comment: @rjpadula 
1. We add the third party SDK to our native code
2. We load a third party JavaScript script that has to communicate with the SDK
3. Our JS code gets notified of events by the third party script
-- Question is whether the third party can use NativeScript to dialogate with the native SDK

Comment: yes, you can use third party SDK if they are not browser specific. I have used Amazon SDK in one of my project.

Comment: @NarendraMongiya "if they are not browser specific" -> the SDK's in question are native